# Convert UserControl To My Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have class that Inherit from UserControl Class.

```
public class Module : UserControl
{
    // Custom Property And Method
}
```

How can i load a UserControl (.ascx) and convert to my Module Class?

UPDATE :

I try all suggest but in best case I get null.
the error is : Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.UC_acsx' to type'BICT.Module'

my class is like this :

```
namespace BICT
{
    public class Module : UserControl
    {
        public Module()
        {
          // Some Initial
        }
        // and some extra property exp.
        public int Index{ get; set;} 
    }
 }
```

is somthing wron with my code?

Comment: This makes a whole lot of NO SENSE....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, by design.

`Module` is a derivative class of `UserControl`. Therefor all `Module` classes can be casted to `UserControl`, but `UserControl` classes can't be casted to `Module` *(see Footnote)*. Read up in inheritence.

***Footnote:** Yes, of course you can cast `UserControl` to `Module`, but only if it is a `Module` in the first place, and is just loaded with the lower type.*

Comment: i made my usercontrol Inherit from module and everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
(Module)Page.LoadControl("Module.ascx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Module module = LoadControl("Module.ascx") as Module;
if(module != null)
{
    //it is an instance module
}
```